# Prove the theorem of row swapping determinants??

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I don't know how to prove this theorem in a clear way, I could really use some help, Thanks so much!

This is a linear-algebra problem dealing with determinants.

> Let M' be the matrix obtained from M by swapping two columns i and j. Show that the det M'=-detM.

*What I know so far*

*Row swapping changes the sign of the determinants

So the columns of M are swapped then M -> -M

And according to the theorem M and M' only differ by a row swap..

...Is there anything else I should say? Does this prove the theorem?

Thanks again

Comment: This is hard to answer because it depends very much on what facts you are allowed to use.  Hint: are you allowed to use the fact that the determinant of a matrix equals the determinant of its transpose?

Comment: Im not absolutely sure I don't see that in the section of the book Im looking at.

Comment: See Freidberg, Insel, and Spence Linear Algebra.

Answer (score 1):

You already know a row swap switches signs.

Then take A transpose. A column change in A is a row change in A transpose.